# Is it benificial to shutdown a computer while not in use?

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure, lifespan

Often times I leave my computer on while waiting for a process, such as a large download, to complete. It's a superstition of mine to turn the computer off as soon as possible after the task has completed. Do computers need "breaks" or can they be left running indefinitely? In particular I'm wondering about the hard drive if it's always spinning while the machine is powered on wouldn't that mean it wares out faster if always on?

I am not asking if it's ok to *always* leave it on, I am asking should one make the effort to shut it down as much as possible?

Comment: See also: [Is it bad to put your computer in sleep mode every time?](http://superuser.com/questions/28582/is-it-bad-to-put-your-computer-in-sleep-mode-every-time) and [Is it more cost efficient to keep my computer on and allow it to go into S4/Hibernate?](http://superuser.com/questions/481178/is-it-more-cost-efficient-to-keep-my-computer-on-and-allow-it-to-go-into-s4-hibe) as well as several others.

Answer (score 1):

There are a [gazillion discussions](https://www.google.com/search?q=ok+to+leave+computer+running]) about leaving the PC on 24/7. There is no winner, it's all opinion or single facts ("I do ..."). Maybe someone can turn up some proper research but I have not found it.

With that in mind, I'd say shut it down when you want to reduce your electricity bill and the power management of the computer is not good enough. To make that a fact instead of an opinion ;-) use one of these plug-in devices that measure the power consumption - that way you can make an actual calculation of the amount of money you are talking about in your case.

[Here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/the-cost-of-leaving-your-pc-on.html)'s an example of someone doing the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the computer in many times reduced life of computer parts, The best situation for computer is to keep computer on.

But it may be costly for you!

Answer (score 0):

Too much time you shutdown your PC will reduce your PC's age, because there are electronical components that have their age.

If you don't use it for a short time, better you leave it alive .. and WINDOWS will take care of it with the power management ..

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter nowadays - every component lifespan is more than the usual exploitation time of modern desktop/laptops.

If you want to reduce the power bill turning off is a good thing. I have kept my PCs turned on 24/7 since 2004 with no problems for the utility of not having to wait a second. Other people turn them on/off few times a day with no problems at all too.